# Eclipse Kura OSGi Dependency Management

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, kura

*Preface: I'm new to Eclipse, OSGi, and Kura*

I'm trying to develop a Kura plug-in that depends on `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient`. I found an OSGi bundle for the package [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5).

Currently, the only way I'm able to use the plug-in (with the OSX Kura emulator) is to download `httpclient-osgi-4.5.jar` and add it to `~/Documents/workspace/target-definition/common/repository/plugins/`. Otherwise I get a class not found error.

When I add the plugin to `MANIFEST.MF` either as with `REQUIRE-PLUGIN` or `IMPORT-PACKAGE`, Eclipse cannot find the package.

What's the correct way to require, fetch, and add to the classpath a remote dependency using Eclipse Kura/OSGi? Eclipse currently only looks in my local workspace for dependancies, is there an accepted way to fetch remote plugins?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The bundles located in target-definition/common/repository/plugins are part of an M2 repository created by the Kura build. It is not enough to simply copy your required bundle to that directory. The solution I typically use to accomplish what you want is:

- Double click the kura-equinox_3.8.1.target file located in target-definition. This should open in the Eclipse IDE.
- Under "Locations", click "Add...". Then select "Directory" and "Next". Select the folder containing your required additional bundles and click "Finish".
- Save the kura-equinox_3.8.1.target file and click "Set as Target Platform". Your new bundle should now be available in Eclipse.

Thanks,

--Dave

Comment: After your answer, I locate also bundle with this way. However, this does not locate the bundle permanently?

Comment: The solution should be permanent, at least for that workspace.

Answer (score 0):

What for me works is;

- Simply copied the bundle in ${workspace_loc}/target-definition/common/repository/plugins
- Clicked on reload
- Clicked on Set as Target Platform

After these steps, Eclipse is aware of my bundle and could able to use it anywhere.